# Keep separate Light and Dark Color classes and use them through one parent class in flutter as const

Tags: flutter, themes, factory-pattern

I have implemented the Light and Dark theme functionality but now I want separate classes for DarkColors and LightColors but I want to access them only through one common parent class i.e. AppColors which would build DarkColors object when dark theme and LightColors object when light theme. I know it is a common factory design pattern problem but I want to implement it as const values so that I'd not have to remove const from the whole app at every single place where AppColors is called already.

These are my sample Light and Dark color Classes:

```
`class LightColors {
  static const Color primaryColor = Colors.white;
  static const Color black54 = Colors.black54;
  static const Color blackColor = Color(0xff2A2F41);
  static const Color redErrorColor = Color(0xffF55353);
  static const Color successGreenColor = Color(0xff0FC982);
  static const Color blueColor = Color(0xff0E65A3);
  static const Color yellowColor = Colors.yellow;
 }

class DarkColors {
  static const Color primaryColor = Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 21, 43);
  static const Color black54 = Colors.white;
  static const Color blackColor = Color(0xff2A2F41);
  static const Color redErrorColor = Color(0xffF55353);
  static const Color successGreenColor = Color(0xff0FC982);
  static const Color blueColor = Color(0xff0E65A3);
  static const Color yellowColor = Colors.yellow;
 }`
```

Here as you can see the colors are different but the attributes are same so when AppColors.primaryColor is used, if its a dark theme it would return a LightColors.primaryColor value and vice versa.

When implementing this as a CONST value, it would be like this:

```
 `Container(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
               color: **AppColors.primaryColor**
             ),
          ),`
```

[EDIT] The themes are also assigned as light and dark and I can use the separate colors there of course,BUT NOT IN THE WHOLE APP WHICH I WANT TO.

```
ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: DarkColors.customOrange,
  appBarTheme: appBarTheme,
  backgroundColor: DarkColors.whiteColor,
  hintColor: DarkColors.bgGrey.withOpacity(0.8),
  errorColor: DarkColors.redErrorColor,
  focusColor: DarkColors.transparent,
)
ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: LightColors.customOrange,
  appBarTheme: appBarTheme,
  backgroundColor: LightColors.whiteColor,
  hintColor: LightColors.bgGrey.withOpacity(0.8),
  errorColor: LightColors.redErrorColor,
  focusColor: LightColors.transparent,
)
```

ANY WAY THE CONST STAYS???

Inside main.dart:

```
 Consumer<ThemeNotifier>(
    builder: (context, ThemeNotifier themeNotifier, _) => MaterialApp(
      title: 'APP',
      themeMode: themeNotifier.themeMode,
      theme: AppTheme().loadTheme(),
      darkTheme: AppTheme().loadTheme(isDark: true),
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
)
```

Comment: You need to assign the following themes for the light and dark mode of the material app, only then you can use the single primaryColor and it would change according light and dark mode

Comment: Already assigned to them. Still the colors are accessed outside the theme data also

Comment: Could you provide the entire code, of how you have assiged it to the light and dark mode of material app

Comment: What is your problem again ? you want to use const values ? Could you elaborate, what actaully you need, and where are you exactly facing problem and what is it

Comment: Please find the main.dart code where the light and dark themes are implemented. My problem is that first change your focus from theme class and consider Color classes separately. I want to use light and dark color values through ONLY their parent class AppColors so that I could use that AppColors class as a light color or dark color depending on the theme which is loaded.